# Conditional replacement of labels based on another data set

Tags: sas

suppose to have the following data set:

> ```
>  ID          Label      
> 0001        0001_1   
> 0001        0001_1   
> 0001        0001_1   
> 0001        0001_1   
> 0001        0001_1   
> 0001        0001_1   
> 0002        0002_1   
> 0002        0002_1  
> 0002        0002_2
> 0002        0002_2
> 0002        0002_3
> 0002        0002_3
> ```

and another one:

> ```
>  ID          Label      
> 0001        0001_1   
> 0001        0001_1   
> 0001        0001_2   
> 0001        0001_2   
> 0001        0001_3   
> 0001        0001_3   
> 0002        0002_1   
> 0002        0002_1  
> 0002        0002_2
> 0002        0002_2
> 0002        0002_3
> 0002        0002_3
> ```

You want the following:
if in the first dataset there is only one type of Label (i.e., 0001_1), the second dataset should have that type. Otherwise if there are multiple labels nothing must be done. The desired output should be:

> ```
>  ID          Label      
> 0001        0001_1   
> 0001        0001_1   
> 0001        0001_1   
> 0001        0001_1   
> 0001        0001_1   
> 0001        0001_1  
> 0002        0002_1   
> 0002        0002_1  
> 0002        0002_2
> 0002        0002_2
> 0002        0002_3
> 0002        0002_3
> ```

Thank you in advance

Best

Comment: And what if there are multiple distinct labels in the first data set?

Comment: So, for some IDs there are multiple Labels and the rule I posted should not be applied. It should be applied only when in the first data set there is a unique Label for the ID.

Comment: Ok. I assume there are multiple IDs in each data set, correct?

Comment: yes, correct! I will edit the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to compute the groups in the first table that have a single label in aggregate and apply that label to the groups in the second table.

Example:

Computation with PROC FREQ and application via MERGE.

```
data have1;
  call streaminit(20231);

  do id = 1 to 10;
    do seq = 1 to rand('integer', 10) + 2;
      if mod(id,2) = 0 
        then label = 'AAA';
        else label = repeat(byte(64+rand('integer', 26)),2);
      output;
    end;
  end;
run;

data have2;
  call streaminit(20232);

  do id = 1 to 10;
    do seq = 1 to rand('integer', 12) + 2;
      label = repeat(byte(64+rand('integer', 26)),2);
      output;
    end;
  end;
run;

proc freq noprint data=have1;
  by id;
  table label / out=one_label(where=(percent=100));
run;

data want2;
  merge 
    have2
    one_label(keep=id label rename=(label=have1label) in=reassign)
  ;
  by id;
  if reassign then label = have1label;
  drop have1label;
run;
```

Same result achieved with SQL code, performing computation in a sub-select and using COALESCE for application.

```
proc sql;
  create table want2 as 
  select 
    have2.id
  , coalesce(singular.onelabel, have2.label) as label
  from 
    have2
  left join 
    ( select unique id, label as onelabel 
      from have1 
      group by id 
      having count(distinct label) = 1
    ) as singular
  on 
    have2.id = singular.id
  ;
```

Comment: Hi Richard, I have a question that why you can use `coalesce()` with two character variables? I think it should be `coalescec()`, but just find both of them work in `proc sql`.

Comment: It's one of those functions implemented differently in Proc SQL because of the procedure's adherence to SQL standards.  The **SQL Procedure Components** section documents `COALESCE` function.  In SQL *COALESCE accepts one or more column names of the same data type. ...*

Comment: Thank you, Richard, you are really knowledgeable.